# How to execute .sh file on Linux MInt 19.3 "Tricia"

Tags: android-studio, sh, linux-mint, shellexecute

I've downloaded android studio from it's official page: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

and I got a .tar.gz file.

After following [this tutorial][1] of "how to install android studio on Linux Mint" I wanted to execute the "studio.sh" file directly like an executable, so I followed some tutorials but i didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on panel > Panel > Panel preferences > Items > Double click on added launcher > Add new empty item >  Set up like the 2nd image.

So I just added a launcher on Panel and set the command like: "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" and I got it! :D

[image: Panel preferences]
[image: Edit Laucher]